# How to combine column from other table

Tags: mysql

I have created 2 temporary tables:

```
--------------      ------------------
| withlabfee |      | without lab fee|
--------------      ------------------  
|   6        |      |       3        |
--------------      ------------------
```

My code returned the following result with single column.

```
-------------------------------
| withlabfee , without lab fee|
------------------------------- 
|   6        ,      3         |
------------------------------
```

My attempted code as below

```
    drop table if exists withlabFee;
    create temporary table withlabFee(labFee1 int);
    insert into withlabFee
        select count(*)
        from course_relation
        where lab_fee is not null;

    drop table if exists withoutLabfee;
    create temporary table withoutLabfee(labFee2 int);
    insert into withoutLabfee
        select count(*)
        from course_relation
        where lab_fee is null;

    select concat(labfee1,',',labfee2) as `With lab fee , Without lab fee`
    from withlabFee, withoutLabfee;

    drop table labFee;
    drop table withoutLabfee;
```

How do i combine the column from my temp table withlabfee and withoutlabfee into 1 table with 2 columns like below:

```
-------------------------------
| withlabfee | without lab fee|
------------------------------- 
|   6        |      3         |
-------------------------------
```

Any helps are very much appreciated!

Comment: `select labfee1, labfee2`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution even without temporary tables:

```
SELECT
  SUM(lab_fee IS NOT NULL) AS 'With lab fee',
  SUM(lab_fee IS NULL) AS 'Without lab fee'
FROM 
  course_relation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query (without creating temp tables).

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN lab_fee IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS withlabFee,
COUNT(CASE WHEN lab_fee IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS withoutLabfee
FROM course_relation
```